# REVISED (for-loops in R)

Tags: r, for-loop

My previous question wasn't well received by the forum, so I'm posting this updated piece of code.  I'm trying to run this for loop on some data to populate each element of a vector with the expression (z-x)/x, but the loop doesn't stop running.  I can't figure out why.

```
for (i in 1:length(corr_data$close)) {
  x <- corr_data$close[i]; z <- corr_data$open[i+1]
  v <- corr_data$company[i]; w <- corr_data$company[i+1]
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  z <- as.numeric(z)
  overnight_ret <- rep(NA,length(corr_data$close))
  if (identical(v, w)){
    overnight_ret[i] <- ((z - x) / x)
  } else {
    overnight_ret <- "Null"
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is only a revision of your other question, then please edit the old question instead of creating a new one. Otherwise it is likely to be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I strongly recommend deleting this question and editing your original question. If you think your original question was poorly received, you are going to be _very_ disappointed in how people react to you re-posting an existing question. Also, this is not a forum. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to for-loop in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143419/how-to-for-loop-in-r)

Comment: first thing, you should probably have `overnight_ret[i] <- NA` instead of what you have now

Comment: because as of now, if v and w are not identical, then you are replacing the vector with a character string and losing all the info. and you will get some weird results if you do something like `tmp[6] <- 6` when tmp is "Null"

Comment: I suggest you trying to generate some example data, so we can try the loop and help you. Please remove one of the questions. Try looking for similar questions to see how they are asked.

Comment: If you have a for-loop ;;  `for (i in 1:length(x)) {...}` ;; and you attempt to extract with index = i+1 ... why do you not expect an error. (I would.)

Comment: I deleted the other thread. Why would I expect an error?  I'm new to programming

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I decided that using loops wasn't a good idea in R, so I just offset the vectors.

```
open <- c(corr_data$open, 0)
close <- c(corr_data$close, 0)
openprice <- c(0, corr_data$open)
closeprice <- c(0, corr_data$close)

overnight_ret = (open - closeprice) / closeprice
```